# Why CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses does not work?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 app which is already published to windows phone store.

it has in-app purchase configured, i use following code when user click "Buy" button in my App.

```
        ListingInformation products = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(new[] { "ProductOne"});

        ProductListing productListing = null;
        if (!products.ProductListings.TryGetValue("ProductOne", out productListing))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find product information");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            string receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productListing.ProductId, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        ProductLicense productLicense = null;
        if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses.TryGetValue("ProductOne", out productLicense))
        {
            if (productLicense.IsActive)
            {
                  ...
            }
            else
            {
                  ...
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the value of productLicense.IsActive is always false.  Can someone tell me, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume since you've got the line of code pinpointed, you're testing on the emulator or deployed from Visual Studio to your device for testing (rather than the version from the App Store)?

It isn't immediately clear to me why `.IsActive` is `False` in your case, but in my app, I've used the [**Mock In-App Purchase Library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#IAP_MockLibrary) which you can download from [**here**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Mock-In-App-Purchase-33080f0c). Using this will basically let you imitate an in-app purchase while debugging, but will also work seamlessly from the Store.

> The library is designed to mimic the way in-app purchase works. When
>   in "Mock Mode" the library maintains a list of your receipts as well
>   as state information for every license. This allows you to exercise
>   the entire browse, search, purchase, and fulfillment flow. When in
>   "Mock Mode" the library doesn’t activate the in-app mock purchase
>   screen, but provides a simple message box to complete the in-app
>   purchase flow while testing in the emulator.

The only thing I can think of for your situation is that you're trying to access the Store while debugging, which I don't think is possible, hence `.IsActive` being `False`.

So if you haven't seen (or aren't already using) the Mock Library, I'd say give it a try. It definitely made my life easier!

Comment: Does IAP require any capability? i unchecked all capabilibies from WMAppmanifest.xml.

Comment: AgeRating = source.AgeRating;  NotImplementedException throw.

Comment: I don't believe it requires any special capabilities, but your app will need certain capabilities to run, obviously, so taking them all out will result in problems. Can you post the section of code that's throwing the exception (maybe that whole function)?

Comment: I too tried Mock IAP. But, After pressing Ok of the message Box of Confirming purchase. Will stays to the same store page. How could i set the free version is false. Because the value i am setting is in mainpage.xaml.cs How could i trigger when pressing ok in simulated purchase.

Comment: What happens if you step through it? Is everything successful?

Comment: @lhan16 It IS possible to access store while debugging.

Comment: @Miloš Only when the products are free